# Is it possible to display a image with java swing that is stored on a google drive without downloading the image?

Tags: java, swing, google-drive-api

I am trying to make an application in java that can manipulate folders and files in my google drive, and would also like to view images from my drive within this application, does anyone know if this is posslible, and if so how?

i have already tried viewing the image with the view link

```
for (File file : imgs)
{
    Image image = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://drive.google.com/open?id=" + 
        file.getId());
        image = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    panel.add(label);
}
```

however ImageIO.read(url) just returns null and results in this exception

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ImgSlider.<init>(ImgSlider.java:28)
    at charSelect.displayChar(charSelect.java:139)
    at charSelect$2.actionPerformed(charSelect.java:87)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
```

Comment: Is the image "public", you may not be able to access the resource without authenticating

Comment: I would consider looking at [Introduction to Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/java) and [Drive API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/drive/v3) as a starting point

Comment: Strictly speaking no, but I guess it would depend how you define downloading.  Any remote resource is download before viewing; any image in a web page is technically download before rendered by the browser.

Comment: i have already looked at them, but i can't find any method of getting the image data without the drive api first having to dowload the file to my system

Comment: yeah, i just want to be able to download it into memory so i can view it, not dowload it to my hard drive

Comment: Oh, wait, I'm dumb, I just didn't read the "download files" good enough in the Introduction to drive API, for some reason I thought they ment to download the file to your hard drive

Comment: Tip: Add @Gavin (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.